# drawing flower with python turtle

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I am learning programming with python (referring think `python 2`) and am struck at a program. Problem statement: `Python program to draw a symmetric flower after seeking the size of and number of petals from user`.

The code i came up with is below, except i am unable to get the angle between each petal mathematically right (part where the code near the end states `bob.lt(360/petal)`). Can someone help here?

```
import math
radius=int(input("What is the radius of the flower? "))
petals=int(input("How many petals do you want? "))
#radius=100
#petals=4


def draw_arc(b,r):  #bob the turtle,corner-to-corner length (radius) of petal (assume 60 degree central angle of sector for simplicity)
    c=2*math.pi*r #Circumference of circle
    ca=c/(360/60)  #Circumference of arc (assume 60 degree central angle of sector as above)
    n=int(ca/3)+1  #number of segments
    l=ca/n  #length of segment
    for i in range(n):
        b.fd(l)
        b.lt(360/(n*6))

def draw_petal(b,r):
    draw_arc(b,r)
    b.lt(180-60)
    draw_arc(b,r)

import turtle
bob=turtle.Turtle()

#draw_petal(bob,radius)

for i in range(petals):
    draw_petal(bob,radius)
    bob.lt(360/petals)

turtle.mainloop()
```

[image: Expected Flower]
Correct (Symmetric)
[image: Incorrect Flower]
Incorrect (Asymmetric)

Comment: 1) Can you give a link to documentation of the Turtle package you imported? 2) What difference do you see between the result that occurred, and the result you were expecting? I.e. how do you know you aren't getting the angle between petals mathematically right? It may help to show a graphic.

Comment: I've updated the original question with the snaps of expectated output at the end... the flower should be symmetrical. The official documentation is here -> https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/turtle.html

Answer (score 2):

Just modify your code like this(in `draw_petals` add `b.rt(360/petals-30` and correct `bob.lt(360/petals)` to `360/4` ):

```
import math
radius=int(input("What is the radius of the flower? "))
petals=int(input("How many petals do you want? "))
#radius=100
#petals=4


def draw_arc(b,r):  #bob the turtle,corner-to-corner length (radius) of petal (assume 60 degree central angle of sector for simplicity)
    c=2*math.pi*r #Circumference of circle
    ca=c/(360/60)  #Circumference of arc (assume 60 degree central angle of sector as above)
    n=int(ca/3)+1  #number of segments
    l=ca/n  #length of segment
    for i in range(n):
        b.fd(l)
        b.lt(360/(n*6))


def draw_petal(b,r):
    draw_arc(b,r)
    b.lt(180-60)
    draw_arc(b,r)
    b.rt(360/petals-30)  # this will take care of the correct angle b/w petals


import turtle
bob=turtle.Turtle()
#draw_petal(bob,radius)

for i in range(petals):
    draw_petal(bob,radius)
    bob.lt(360/4)
```

Comment: I don't see the justification for keeping the line `bob.lt(360/4)` rather than fix it to be `bob.lt(360 / petals)` -- it seems like you've over corrected the code in `draw_petal()` to counter and preserve errors elsewhere rather than actually correct them.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out @cdlane. I was testing with 4 petals, and you were right in me over-correcting.. my intention was to use `bob.lt(360/petals)`

Comment: Thanks @Tarptaeya. Considering my error in the original post (regarding `bob.it(360/petals)` your solution works perfectly for 4 petals.. not more, not less. Correcting the original question now...

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is simpler than you're making it.

The first issue is that drawing a petal changes the turtle heading and you're trying to do math to set it back to where it started.  Here we can just record the heading before drawing the petal and restore it afterward, no math.

The second issue is you're implementing your own arc code when turtle can do this using an extent argument to `turtle.circle()` which produces the same result but much faster:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

def draw_petal(turtle, radius):
    heading = turtle.heading()
    turtle.circle(radius, 60)
    turtle.left(120)
    turtle.circle(radius, 60)
    turtle.setheading(heading)

my_radius = int(input("What is the radius of the flower? "))
my_petals = int(input("How many petals do you want? "))

bob = Turtle()

for _ in range(my_petals):
    draw_petal(bob, my_radius)
    bob.left(360 / my_petals)

bob.hideturtle()

screen = Screen()
screen.exitonclick()
```

**USAGE**

```
> python3 test.py
What is the radius of the flower? 100
How many petals do you want? 10
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Dear @cdlane ,OP doesn't want alternate solution he just want to correct his original code

Comment: @OP, the correction to the original code is the `heading = turtle.heading()` and `turtle.setheading(heading)` in `draw_petal()`. This is exactly right, and should be the accepted answer. The other improvements are also valuable.